# Based on a given address (or coordinates), how do I return the name of the neighborhood the address is in?

Tags: excel, vba, api, excel-formula, geocode

I am in the process of working through a few problems in excel in hopes to turn them into a macro. I am relatively proficient in excel, but still new to the world of APIs and VBA. I am looking for a solution for the following problem: given an address(or coordinates, I have both), I want a formula /process that will take that address, look it up and return the name of the neighborhood that the address is in.

For example: If I had a cell that reads "910 E Hadley St, Milwaukee, WI 53212", I would want the cell next to it to return the value "Riverwest". I know there is a way to do this, I just don't know where to start. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

I have tried playing around with Excel's Geo Data, but I found you cannot pull data on individual addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your address field to type = Geography and then use Excel geography.

[have a look at this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-geographic-location-data-287b4cf2-3d7d-4bc1-b412-3d00f45dbbd6)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).